# Reference Value Parameter VS Return value which one is good?

Tags: c#

When we want to modify some value in one object we may use two different methods, just want to know which one is better or there is no big different between them.

  1.

```
  

void SomeMethod()
   {
      UserInfo newUser = New UserInfo();
      ModifyUserInfo(newUser);
      //Modify UserInfo after calling void method GetUserInfo
   }




           void ModifyUserInfo(UseerInfo userInfo)
           {
               userInfo.UserName = "User Name";
               .....
           }
```

  2.

```
  
    void SomeMethod()
       {
          UserInfo newUser = New UserInfo();
          //Assign new userinfo explicitly
          newUser = GetUserInfo(newUser);

       }


       UserInfo ModifyUserInfo(UseerInfo userInfo)
       {
           userInfo.UserName = "User Name";
           .....
           return userInfo;
       }
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question in the format of this site. Read Uncle Bob's book Clean Code to get an answer.

Comment: Your second snippet creates the impression that it creates a new object.  It doesn't, don't use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer a third:

```
   void SomeMethod()
   {
      UserInfo newUser = GetUserInfo();
   }


   UserInfo GetUserInfo()
   {
       UserInfo userInfo = New UserInfo();
       userInfo.UserName = "User Name";
       .....
       return userInfo;
   }
```

Basically this lets `GetUserInfo` handle all of the details of building up `UserInfo`, and your calling code does not have to worry about *any* of the details other than the object it is getting back.

Comment: Hmmm. What if the method takes an existing `UserInfo` and fills in the email, company, fax, etc while leaving the other fields intact?

Comment: If going that route why not just let a UserInfo constructor take care of it? Oh, and I agree with andras. ModifyUserInfo has more uses then a one time construction of UserInfo

Comment: Good points; I was trying to keep my code close to his. But a (still) better implementation probably would be as a class that initializes everything via a constructor and provides either properties or a Modify() method to handle updates to an existing object.

Comment: Andras's idea is same as mine. I just want to compare pres and cons of return object by explicit return or implicit return by reference object. In my current project we use first method handle all transaltor from datareader to object(Entity).

Comment: Justin: point taken, but you assume that the OP has control over UserInfo. Let's see how you'd extend UserInfo in that case: say that you are in 3.5 - another assumption - and create an extension method. What would the signature of that method be? Wouldn't it be `static void ModifyUserInfo(this UserInfo userinfo, string username)`? :) Also, the OP might want to go for separating operations and ditch even extension methods. There are many legitimate reasons for this. (WCF, manager pattern, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

From the second signature - `UserInfo ModifyUserInfo(UseerInfo userInfo)` -, I might assume that it will treat `UserInfo` as if it was *immutable*.

I might be mislead into thinking that it will *make a copy* of the object passed in, and *return a new*, modified one.

Answer (score 0):

First method is OK. This is not reference parameter, passing by reference is: ref UserInfo userInfo, and it is not recommended. One of FxCop rules is: Do not pass types by reference, but this is not what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Flippant answer: **None of them** are good. This is:

```
UserInfo newUser = New UserInfo(); 
newUser.Modify();
```

or, if UserInfo is better modeled as a **Value Object**:

```
UserInfo newUser = New UserInfo();
var u = newUser.Modify();
```

although in the latter case, I'd probably name the method something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can even have

```
UserInfo ui = new UserInfo {UserName = "User Name", ...}
```

(in C# 3.0). But in general, if this is a reference-type, don't instantiate it every time, unless it's really needed (like for System.String)- I'm talking about 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

The first method. The second doesn't make any sense; without examining the code (or documentation) there's no way to know that it returns the same instance of UserInfo that is passed in.